# how to access the Selected value of an HTML.Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have the following inside my view in an asp.net mvc web application:-

```
 @Html.DropDownList("siteName", ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.SDOrganization>)ViewBag.sites).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
            Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.NAME), 
            Value = option.NAME,
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Resource.SiteDefinition != null ) && (Model.Resource.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization != null) && (option.NAME.ToUpper() == Model.Resource.CI.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME.ToUpper())
        }), "Choose...")
```

but currently the drop down list will always show "Choose", instead of displaying the value associated with the current model object. baring in mind that if i write the following directly inside my view     `@Model.Resource.CI.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME.ToUpper();` it will show correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this signature of the DropDownList method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel
)
```

And, this constructor of the SelectList class:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    Object selectedValue
)
```

So, do it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("siteName", new SelectList(ViewBag.sites, Model.Resource.CI.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME), "None")
```

But, make sure your `ViewBag.sites` does not have any null values. Also, follow the standard naming conventions. Use "SiteName", instead of "siteName", and "Sites" instead of "sites". And, most important of all, add SiteName to your ViewModel, and use the Strongly-Typed version of DropDownList, like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SiteName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Sites, Model.SiteName), "None")
```

Comment: Thanks for yuor kind answer. but what if the Model is null or the Model.Resource is null. will it raise an exception. ?

Comment: If the Model is null, you don't want to display anything in your View, right? So, just put the DropDownList inside an if clause, and check if the Model is not null.

Comment: you are right , i can check if the model if null or not. but i am trying to avoid this kind of checking on the view and to keep my view as clean as possible.

Comment: Is this a partial view? Because, if it's not a partial view, I can't see any reason why the Model can be null. If it's a partial view, and the Model is actually a nullable property of another Model, then there's nothing wrong with checking if the Model is null or not.